# R - Writing data to CSV in a loop

Tags: r, loops, csv, for-loop, export-to-csv

I have a loop that is going through a list of variables (in a csv), accessing a database and extracting the relevant data. It does this for 4 different time periods (which depend on the variables).

I am trying to get R to write this data to a csv, but at current I can only get it to store the data for the last variable in 4 different csv files as it overwrites the previous variable each time.

I'd like it to have all of the data for these variables for one time period all in the same file/sheet. (So either 4 sheets or 4 csv files with all of the data on them) This is because I need to do some data manipulation on the variables before I feed them into the next loop of the script.

I'd like it to be something like this, but need 4 separate sheets/files so I can cover each time period.

```
date/time  | var1 | var2 |  ...  | varn
```

I would post the code, but even only posting the relevant loop and none of the surrounding code would be ~150 lines. **I am not familiar with R (I can follow the script but struggle writing my own)**, I inherited this project and don't have long to work on it.

Note: each variable is recorded at a different frequency - some will only have one data point an hour, others one every minute, so will need to match these up based on time recorded (to the nearest minute).

EDIT: I hope I've explained this clearly enough

Comment: have you tried write.csv(..., append = T) ?

Comment: What @Henk said. Alternatively, you can use connections to avoid the overhead of opening/closing each time.

Comment: Are you trying to write everything to one file, or four different files? Maybe you can only post the code that writes to file, and not the data-reading part.

Comment: @Heroka Currently it is a simple `write.csv(VarS,file="DataS.csv")` at the end of the loop (except that there's 4 of them).

Comment: @Henk, append =T does not appear to have done anything differently, the last variable is the only one saved still.

Comment: @Henk R is ignoring the append completely "In write.csv(...,append = T) : attempt to set 'append' ignored"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four different .csv files would be easiest, because you could do something like the following in your loop:

```
outfile.name <- paste('Sales', year.of.data, sep='')
write.csv(outfile.name, out.filepath, row.names=FALSE)
```

You could also append the data into one data.frame and then export it all at once into one sheet. You won't be able to export to multiple sheets for a .csv, because a CSV won't let you have multiple sheets.

Comment: Understood, 4 files it is. I'm unsure how I would go about appending it to a dataframe, would this be able to match up the times of the data points?

Comment: If the files are all formatted the same with the same variable names, you can read them in and rbind them (i.e., append or stack them). If you need more specifics, I'd edit your post to include some of your data (by using dput). Also, welcome to SO - if you find the answer useful an upvote would be appreciated, and if it ends up solving your problem you could mark it as correct.

Comment: This is almost there, however there are gaps in the data (different sampling rates) and it is currently tiling the data to fill the gaps (e.g. only 10 data items for one variable, compared to 60 for another, then those 10 get repeated 6 times) I guess if I could match up the time stamps in some way I could avoid this?

Comment: It is tough to tell without seeing the data, but that sounds like a different issue. If I solved your issue above, I'd appreciate a vote and even marking the answer as correct, and then you can open another question with additional data.

Comment: it is in the main post up top.